# что значит желтая подсветка в vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как исправить эту ошибку? первый раз задаю вопрос, прошу прощения если что то делаю не так :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: картинка]

снизу-слева должна быть информация об ощибках, у вас что-то с ассоциацией файла, такое ощущение, что VSCode видит этот код не как javaScript. Возможно вы что-то затронули в настройках

Comment: убрал в начале "use strict" ошибок стало меньше

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, добавил там картинку, помогите разобраться в ошибках

Comment: попробуйте использовать let вместо const. У вас какие-то проблемы с JSHint, к сожалению я не знаю что это. Ошибка говорит о том, что `const доступен в ES6`. скорей всего ваш VSCode видит код как ES5 или ниже, это мое предположение

Comment: спасибо я решил проблему, балгодаря вам

Comment: в чем была проблема?